# Generic method without type argument

Tags: java, generics

I was wondering if there's a way to, in Java, use a generic type within a generic method without requiring an argument specifying the class type. Here's the normal way of doing it:

```
public <T> T doSomethingGeneric(Class<T> type, int a) {
    return (T) doSomethingElse(type, a);
}
```

I would like this as an alternative:

```
public <T> T doSomethingGeneric(int a) {
    return (T) doSomethingElse(/* some magic with T here */, a);
}
```

Background: I'm writing utility methods with Hibernate. Here's an example of what I'm actually trying to do, and you can infer how it applies to this problem.

```
public static <M extends Model> M get(Class<M> type, Serializable id) {
    Session session = newSession();
    Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
    Object model = null;
    try {
        model = session.get(type, id);
        t.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        t.rollback();
        throw ex;
    }
    return (M) model;
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how is it done? Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you writing your own `get()` method and not using [`EntityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html)?

Comment: Because I'm new to Hibernate and didn't know that EntityManager existed. Thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: In that case, I strongly recommend at least skimming the relevant part of the Java EE tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to get a `Class<T>` at runtime to pass to `doSomethingElse()`? [No, that is not possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8436055/139010)

If you describe why `doSomethingElse` needs a `Class<T>`, perhaps we could suggest a workaround.

Comment: I'm writing utility methods with Hibernate. Here's an example of what I'm actually trying to do, and you can infer how it applies to this problem: https://gist.github.com/blakeman8192/de57273f472ceaf1b7d8

Comment: Yeah, this isn't possible. That's why `Session#get()` needs a `Class<T>` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible: the code of `doSomethingGeneric` is only compiled once, unlike the instantiation of a template in C++. The type `T` is *erased* to `Object` in the process.

Notice also that `(T)` will be flagged as an unchecked downcast.