# Passing in a Type reference to a method

Tags: java, generics

I want to write a method that will create a List of the type I define in the method parameters. So if I have 3 classes: `Student`, `Teacher` and `Janitor`, the method should create a `List` of whatever type is passed in

```
public void methodName(TYPE){  
    List<TYPE> results = new List<TYPE>();  
}
```

What should I be using for `TYPE`?

Comment: You probably want to take a look at Java generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JAVA generics. One way is to allow all class types to be acceptable, by this..

```
public <T> void methodName(Class<T> cl){  
    List<T> results = new ArrayList<T>();  
}
```

or a better way would be to make all classes you want to be accepted derive from an interface, say `Person` and then you can do..

```
public <T extends Person> void methodName(Class<T> cl){  
    List<T> results = new ArrayList<T>();  
}
```

This limits the set of classes accepted by the the method, to only those implementing `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but one option is as follows:

```
public <T>
void methodName(Class<T> clazz) {

    List<T> results = new ArrayList<T>();
    ...
}
```

You could then call it as:

```
methodName(Student.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If these three classes can inherit from a single class or implement a single interface then your method signature can be like this:

```
public List<ParentClass/Interface> methodName(TYPE);
```

If three class cannot be related to a common contract as mentioned above then other choice will be to return the list of Objects and cast the objects appropriately when you iterate the list of objects:

```
public List<Object> methodName(TYPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [a question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8436055/483113), which, however, approaches the issue from the other side.

Basically Java has such a function already (feel free to go from there):

```
Collections.<String>emptyList()
```

to get an empty List with elements which are supposedly of type String. Java's source looks like this:

```
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList<Object>();
:
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
  return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```