# Why does ternary operator fail with a type mismatch error?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, type-inference, ternary-operator

I have the following simple code piece:

```
List<XXXXBean> queryPeriodData()
{
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(res))
    {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    return res;
}
```

It works.

but if I change to this, there is a compile error...

```
return CollectionUtils.isEmpty(res) ? Collections.emptyList() : res;
```

error message is 
**"Type mismatch: cannot convert from List< capture#1-of ? extends Object> to List< XXXXBean>"**

I don't know the difference between the two way.

Comment: I used the Eclipse Luna Release and with jdk 1.7.0_67.

Comment: Use `return Collections.<XXXXBean>emptyList()` to make ensure type compatibility between the two possible values.  See [Collections.emptyList() returns a List<Object>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306713/collections-emptylist-returns-a-listobject) for a detailed discussion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ternary ? operator vs the conventional If-else operator in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643137/ternary-operator-vs-the-conventional-if-else-operator-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Type inference has improved in Java 8. Your second example now works.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [Ternary ? operator vs the conventional If-else operator in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643137/ternary-operator-vs-the-conventional-if-else-operator-in-c-sharp), this question is about type-reference, and that is about performance.

Comment: and this is java, it has nothing to do with c# :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `Collections.<XXXXBean>emptyList()` in the statement

Comment: Is the difference due to: in first example, for statement "return Collections.emptyList(); " compiler can figure out the return type. but in second example, in "Collections.emptyList()" expression, the compiler doesn't know the return type, so it returns List<Object> by default. Is it right?