# Type mismatch with byte variable using ternary operator

Tags: java, conditional-operator

```
int a = 10, b = 20;
byte x = (a>b) ? 10 : 20;
```

The preceding code produces a Compile-Time error saying: Type mismatch cannot convert from int to byte.

It's weird that when i replace the expression (a>b) with (true) the code successfully compiles!
Also when I replace the expression with literals (10>20) the code also works!!

Not only that but also when I explicitly type cast 10, 20 or even the whole ternary operator the code works too!

```
byte x = (a>b) ? (byte)10 : 20;
byte x = (a>b) ? 10 : (byte)20;
byte x = (byte)((a>b) ? 10 : 20);
```

What is exactly wrong with the expression (a>b)?

Note that equavalent code using if-else works fine.

```
int a = 10, b = 20;
byte x;
if(a>b) {
    x = 10;
} else {
    x = 20;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because when the expression is directly specified with numbers like `(10>20)`, then expression is evaluated at compile time itself and result value is assigned to byte variable. If you use any IDE you can see the warning of `Dead code` in this expression

```
byte x = (20>10) ? 10 : 20 (Dead code); // because compiler know 20 greater than 10 and assigns 10 to x
```

But while using variables `a,b` compiler doesn't know those values at compile time and the expression is evaluated at runtime. Since in java by default numeric values are represented as `int` it is asking explicit type casting

```
byte x = (a>b) ? 10 : 20;  //Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte
```

And i would suggest to read this for [type casting with ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002603/why-does-the-ternary-operator-unexpectedly-cast-integers)

Comment: (a>b) is just a condition that is independently evaluated to either true or false. I can assign both 10 and 20 to a byte variable directly with no issue. ex: byte x = 10; Neither a nor b will be stored into x. Why does the compiler complain?

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason you can do this:

```
        int a = 10;
        byte x = 10;
        System.out.println("a: " + x);
```

but you can't do this:

```
        int a = 10;
        byte x = a; <-- java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
        System.out.println("a: " + x);
```

Direct assignment of an `int` to a `byte` using the literal is a narrowing conversion. It doesn't violate the type system because Java will happily lop the significant bits off a literal `10` and present you with a `byte`.

But if you tell it `a`  is an int, it can't be a `byte` (because a `byte` isn't and `int`).

Comment: I understand that but both a & b variables are not part of the returned result that will be stored into the variable x. Shouldn't the expression (a>b) just produces a true or false only?

Comment: as @Deadpool says, the compiler is replacing the if with a direct assignment is the same as my first example. Leaving it to be dynamically resolved sends you down into the depths of the Java Language Spec.

Answer (score 0):

Kind a similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799249/why-does-ternary-operator-fail-with-a-type-mismatch-error), but not exactly.
I tried going through language specification and few other resources, but there was no purely exact answer, on how the operand types are choosen by the compiler.

But assembiling all the info it seems that the:

```
byte x = (a>b) ? 10 : 20;
```

produces the error, because there's an implicit convertion of type `int` to `byte`.
In newer java versions the compilator shows:

```
error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
```

This is because the second and third operand in `(a>b) ? 10 : 20` is considered as `int`. The basic numeric constants are always evaluated to `int` and they need to be explicitly downcasted to `byte`.
Casting the return (second or third) operands or the whole statement to byte prevents the error, because it explicitly shows to the compiler that data loss of casting `int` to `byte` shouldn't be taken into consiteration.

Casting second or third operand to `byte` explicitly says that every return from that ternary operator should be treated as `byte`.

Writing something like:

```
int aa = 100000000;
byte zz = aa;
//or
double dd = 10.11d;
long xyx = dd;
```

will result in same kind of an error.

The reason behind all of this is in that, the promoting of smaller primitive to upper one doesn't impact the deterministic result of a program, but downcasting (i.e. int to short) or dropping the floating point can output in different results.
See that, such declarations doesn't produce any error:

```
byte ooo = 100; //it throws an error if the value of ooo is higher than 127
//cause the `127` is the max value for byte type
int iii = ooo;
```

The line like:

```
byte x = (20>10) ? 10 : 20;
```

doesn't output in any runtime/compiller error, because while having explicit values provided to the condition compiler can simply evaluate condition which results in: `byte x = 10`.
The dead code, aka unreachable statement in Java could be produced with:

```
try {
    throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Exception(e);
    System.out.println(); //compiler shows this line as unreachable
}
```

So, for a short conclusion, the number literals/constants are evaluated as `int` type if they aren't explicitly assigned to the specific type. The `byte x = 10;` works, because it explicitly says to assign `10` to byte type, and `10` is in scope of `byte` type and doesn't leads to any data loss (assigning `-129` or `10.1` throws an error).

The thing with `byte x = (a>b) ? 10 : 20;` is that, the whole ternary expression isn't evaluated on fly, the compiler doesn't know if the values of `a` and `b` aren't being changed somewhere else. Stating explicit numbers or just `true/false` in condition of ternary operator makes the result of an expression obvious to the compiler (and to developer eyes).

After a better look into spec of [conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html) it says:

> The conditional operator ? : uses the boolean value of one expression to decide which of two other expressions should be evaluated.

Having this stated, the choosen result operator is evaluatd **ONLY** when the condition operator is evaluated (1st result if true, 2nd if false).
Explicit condition like `20>10` or `true` is evaluated at compile time, so the exact, explicit value is assigned in case of `byte x = ...`.

Why does something such small as:

```
int a = 10, b = 20;
byte x = (a>b) ? 10 : 20;
```

isn't being evaluated at compile time and throws an error?
As already stated number literals are evaluated to `int` and in above assignment to `x` variable isn't explicit (reminding the choosen result operator are evaluated after the condition is evaluated).
The compiler isn't something like a full static code analyzer, trying to request a compiler do to so could result in overcomplicated byte code.
Imagine some more complex example where the values of `a` and `b` are initialized in code but there are several `if` statements which could change the values assigned to `a` or `b`. Then compiler must first check if any of if statement can be evaluated at compile time, to determine if there is a compiletime value for one of those variables and later produce conditions for the `ternary/conditional operator` based on that if one of those values have changed. And in the result providing a lot of much complex code then it would do without such analyzes.

This is a very simple example, so for the dev it can look like `wtf`, but for compiler preventing such case would be too much overhead, becasuse the compiler can't tell if the provided code is simple or not and cannot evaluate the variable values for conditions at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

This may be redundant with all the other answers, but it's how I convinced myself. `a.compareTo(b)` can clearly not be evaluated at compile time, and integer literals are always default `int`:

```
String a = "a", b = "b";
byte x = (a.compareTo(b) > 1) ? 10 : 20;
```

produces the same compile time error:

```
error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
    byte x = (a.compareTo(b) > 1) ? 10 : 20;
                                  ^
```

Floating points are default double, so this also produces a similar error:

```
float x = (a.compareTo(b) > 1) ? 10.0 : 20.0;
```