# How do I represent an empty list in java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have this class has constructor taking a String and a Arraylist as argument;

```
class Foo{
    String ide;
    ArrayList list;

    public TypeOperator(String ide, ArrayList list){
        this.ide = ide;
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

so when I initialise the class like below:

```
Foo one = new Foo("boo", []);
```

it gives errors. Well I can do this to make it work:

```
ArrayList empty = new ArrayList();
Foo one = new Foo("boo", empty);
```

is there any reason why the first solution won't work? Or is there a way to make some changes to make it work? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use [Collections.emptyList](http://stackoverflow.com/a/306773/884561)?

Comment: AFAIK, `[]` on its own isn't a thing in Java. And in languages where it is a thing (PHP, JS, ...) it usually means "Array", which is a different thing than "ArrayList".

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 11):

To represent an Empty List in Java (an ArrayList *is a* List), we use [`java.util.Collections.emptyList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--).

So you could use something like this:

`Foo foo = new Foo("boo", (ArrayList) java.util.Collections.emptyList());`

In case you need other ways to create a new list in java, see this answer [How to make a new List in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858572/how-to-make-a-new-list-in-java).

Now you may have mixed up Arrays with ArrayList, resulting in usage of an array like syntax, [], to create an ArrayList. But that too is off mark from the language specifications, and you can read more about how to create arrays from SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array), or as is always better, the standard java docs.

And, not related to your question, but you should [always code to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).

Answer (score 1):

Your class `Foo` has a wrong constructor name, the correct should be:

```
class Foo {
  String ide;
  ArrayList list;

  public Foo(String ide, ArrayList list){
    this.ide = ide;
    this.list = list;
  }
}
```

Your first solution is wrong because you are not passing an instance of ArrayList to the constructor. In order to create an empty ArrayList, you may use:

```
Foo one = new Foo("boo", new ArrayList());
```

You may rewrite the Foo class to use the generic type of List:

```
class Foo {
  String ide;
  List list;

  public Foo(String ide, List list){
    this.ide = ide;
    this.list = list;
  }
}
```

... and use the `java.util.Collections.EMPTY_LIST` to represent empty lists:

```
Foo one = new Foo("boo", Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
```

Answer (score 0):

The TypeOperator function definition expects an argument of type ArrayList. The example is attempting to pass an empty array literal.

The first solution is incorrect because there is a type mismatch between ArrayList and [].

A possible solution would be changing the function definition to

```
    public TypeOperator(String ide, <some-type>[] list){
        this.ide = ide;
        this.list = new ArrayList(list);
    }
```

which could be called via

```
    TypeOperator("somestring", new <some-type> [<some-dimension>]);
```